# Give each posts in a loop a number in sequence

Tags: loop, count

In my homepage, I have 10 latest posts.
I want to display numbers starting from 0-9 in each post.
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a presentational thing, I'd be inclined to use CSS (there are of course ways of doing it in PHP, and others may disagree.)

You'd make use of the [counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) and [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) properties.

CSS counters can be applied to any element, not just ordered-lists (`<ol></ol>`) and added using [pseudo-elements](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/) and you can control the starting number and how it is incremented (counters can even run in reverse.)

They have [very high browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters) (essentially IE8 and above, and anything else.)

Here's some code for the [twentyfourteen theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen/):

```
.home .site-content {
    counter-reset: posts -1;
}

.home article {
    counter-increment: posts;
}

.home .entry-title:before {
    content: counter(posts) '. ';
}
```

Note:

- Not compatible with pagination, as list will still start at 0 on subsequent pages
- The counter has to have a unique name - "posts"
- The counter is incremented for each `<article>` tag
- You want the first item to be 0, so we have to start at minus 1, because the first article will increment it by 1
- Only tested in latest Chrome and Firefox, but 97% global browser support as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks but I will not prefer to use your css way. I had thought so big about this, therefore it overshadowed my brain. actually I had found what I was looking for.

Comment: <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
 <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
 $i = 0; 
 $post_id = get_the_ID();
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

 <?php echo $i; ?>

 <?php
 $i++;
 endwhile;
 endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>